# Visual Studio csproj error during build in Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

I'm getting the following error when deploying a project in Visual Studio online and have no idea how to fix it, any help much appreciated:

> C:\a\src\project\Web Application.csproj (76): The element <#text> beneath element <ItemGroup> is unrecognized.

Answer (score 2):

This error was caused due to a syntax error on my part, had two quotes for one of the lines.  Once removed, it fixed the problem.